# Buying under my bid price

Tags: stocks

I buy low-priced and penny stocks a lot. I run into this situation *constantly* (even on higher-priced stocks.) I bid, say, $.10 (with no qualifiers) on 1000 shares on a stock currently selling for $.15. It will creep lower toward my bid (sometimes over a 6-month time-frame) and suddenly one day it sells—*to someone else*—for $.07, 3-cents below my bid. The next day it will pop back up to $.12 or $.15 and I get filled on no shares at my bid price. Is this not a "bidding process?" If I'm bidding higher, why don't I get filled first? Why does someone else get to buy the stock I want *cheaper* than my bid price?

Comment: Your question itself may be valid, but I'll just point out the ever-present caveat that penny stocks are *extremely* volatile, and I'd advise you not to invest in anything if you don't understand the mechanics of how it works.

Comment: What exchange is this on? It's possible that the lower bid had an all-or-nothing bid that matched the market order perfectly, but I have never heard of an exchange skipping the highest bid just to match an all-or-nothing order.

Comment: Happens all the time to me. Scottrade gives me different mumbo jumbo about Market Makers every time I ask them to explain. Never makes sense to me. As far as wisdom goes… too late. But if I can double-up, or better, reducing my cost by 50%, or more for $50…I'll take the chance, sometimes.

Comment: @Kenfro If you are getting responses from your broker and don't understand it (calling it "mumbo jumbo") it would be highly advisable for you to stop trading until you *do* understand what is happening. The less you understand about where your money is going, the more this becomes 'gambling' instead of 'investing'.

Comment: @Kenfro Related: [Can brokers execute my OTC stock orders at inferior prices by “trading through”?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/131451/can-brokers-execute-my-otc-stock-orders-at-inferior-prices-by-trading-through)

Answer (score 7):

It definitely depends on the exchange you are trading on. I'm not familiar with Scottrade, but a standard practice is to fulfill limit orders in the order they are placed.

Most of the time, you wouldn't see stocks trade significantly under your bid price, but since penny stocks are very volatile, it's more likely their price could drop quickly past your bid and then return above it while only fulfilling a portion of the orders placed.

**Example**
1. Penny stock priced at $0.12
2. *Others* place limit orders to buy at $0.10
3. *You* place limit order to buy at $0.10
4. Stock price drops to $0.07 and some orders are filled (anything $0.07 or higher) based on a first-come first-served basis
5. Due to the increase in purchases of the penny stock, the price rises above $0.10 before your order is filled

*****EDIT***** - Adding additional clarification from comment section.

**A second example**
If the price drops from $0.12 to $0.07, then orders for all prices from $0.07 and above will start to be filled from the oldest order first. That might mean that the oldest order was a limit buy order for 100 shares at $0.09, and since that is above the current ask price, it will be filled first. The next order might be for 800 shares at $0.07. It's possible for a subset of these to be filled (let's say 400) before the share's price increases from the increased demand. Then, if the price goes above $0.10, your bid will not be filled during that time.

Comment: Also "Stock price drops to $0.07" would mean that some order is filled at 0.07, which is the heart of the problem. A 0.10 buy order should be filled before a 0.07 buy order regardless of when they come it, so your first sentence should read "standard practice is to fulfill limit orders _at the same price_ in the order they are placed"

Comment: @DStanley I don't think that's necessarily true. In fact, I'm certain that's not true on at least some exchanges. I've often seen the oldest-placed order filled first, regardless of whether there were higher priced bids out there.

Comment: @MichaelBianchi So if person A submits a $100 limit sell order, then person B submits a $1 limit sell order, and I place a market buy order, I'm forced to buy at $100 because person A was there first?

Comment: All good explanations and I believe all have happened to me at one time or other. The Mumbo-Jumbo explanation that confused me was that the S-T rep did tell me that he "oldest order was filled first," while I was always under the impression that it was a bidding process as D Stanley described. Thank you all.

Comment: @DStanley Let me clarify a little. If the price drops from $0.12 to $0.07, then orders for all prices from $0.07 and above will start to be filled from the oldest order first. That might mean that the oldest order was a limit buy order for 100 shares at $0.09, and since that is above the current ask price, it will be filled first. The next order might be for 800 shares at $0.07. It's possible for a subset of these to be filled (let's say 400) before the shares price increases from the increased demand. Then, if the price goes above $0.10, your bid will not be filled during that time.

Comment: Great answer - and it highlights well how the volatility and low liquidity of penny stocks can add a great deal of risk to an investor [in a well-traded stock, the price wouldn't be as likely to jump back up quickly after dipping].

Comment: OK. I've had an order for shares of QRMLF @ $.002 sitting out there for months. Several times it has traded at .001 without filling my order. I did get some at .002 before it jumped back up to .02. So, I'm waiting for the other shares at .002. But if ANY of my shares filled, then it would seem to me that I would be first in line, would it not? But today 12,000 shares have traded at .001 — without me getting any shares at my higher bid. Forget about me, how is that fair to the seller?

Comment: @Kenfro I don't know if I'd consider it fair myself, but the seller is still getting at least their ask price or else they wouldn't be selling it. So, it's a win-win for the seller and buyer.

Comment: OK. As I said, I've had a buy order for QRMLF @ .002 sitting out there for months and having been partially filled at that price weeks ago, it seems I should have been first in line. Today it opened at .002—no fill. I also had an order @ .001 and added one @ .006. Today QRMLF dropped in the afternoon to .001—still no fill. It popped up to .006 late in the day—THEN I got filled.

Answer (score 0):

With all the algorithms used, it's possible your bid hadn't 'officially' been placed by Scottrade.  They may have put your bid on a 'hold' until the price got close, then Scottrade places the order.  But, someone else's bid at .07 was filled before Scottrade's order for you hit the queue.  I believe that has to happen more than people realize.  I just watched a bid I placed 2 hours before, .50 lower than the current price. There were no bids on LVL2 at that price when I placed my order.  Saw 20,000 shares get sold at or below my 500 qty bid price, and then back up above it again.  The second time it dropped to that price it got filled (about 20min later). The system puts retail investors at a distinct disadvantage.